# Using group_by to replace different strings by group

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to replace every instance of an author's name in a data.frame with a different string, but only when that author was the one speaking. For instance, if we have the data:

`test <- data.frame(author = c("jon", "mike", "sam"), text = rep("jon and mike mike and sam sam sam", 3))`

I'd like to replace every instance of "sam" with some other text when `author=="sam"`.

I've tried using `do` and `str_replace_all` to do this, but haven't gotten it to work:

`test %>% group_by(author) %>% do(mutate(., text2 = str_replace(.$text, eval(parse(text = .$author)), "yay")))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`str_replace_all` is *Vectorised over string, pattern and replacement.* (see `?str_replace_all`), so you can just use the `author` column as `pattern`:

```
test %>% mutate(new_text = str_replace_all(text, author, 'yay'))

#  author                              text                          new_text
#1    jon jon and mike mike and sam sam sam yay and mike mike and sam sam sam
#2   mike jon and mike mike and sam sam sam   jon and yay yay and sam sam sam
#3    sam jon and mike mike and sam sam sam jon and mike mike and yay yay yay
```

Comment: For some reason I'm getting this error: `Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: no applicable method for 'type' applied to an object of class "factor".` - any idea what I'm doing differently/wrong? I just copy/pasted what you wrote.

Comment: You probably have the columns as factor instead of character, try `stringsAsFactors=F` when constructing the data frame. I used this `test <- data.frame(author = c("jon", "mike", "sam"), text = rep("jon and mike mike and sam sam sam", 3), stringsAsFactors = F)`

Comment: That solved it! Thanks - I'll accept your answer as soon as the wait-period is over.

Comment: Cool. Glad it helps!